# Daily correlation in R

Tags: r

I would like to compute the daily correlation coefficient and p-value between multiple variables. The data has a resolution of 1 hour and was measured for 5 months. My data set looks like this:

```
DateTime          Variable 1   Variable 2  Variable 3
[POSIXct]           [num]        [num]       [num]
2019-05-01 00:45             
2019-05-01 01:45
2019-05-01 02:45
2019-05-01 03:45
...
```

Here i would like to compute the correlation between Variable 1 and Variable 2, and the correlation between Variable 1 and Variable 3. The results (correlation coefficient and p-value) should be stored in a data frame.

So far i have been able to compute and save the correlation and p-value for the entire time period (giving me one correlation coefficient for my whole data set). With the following code:

```
b <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=3))
colnames(b) <- c("Variable", "estimate", "p.value")

for (i in 2:3) {
  a <-  cor.test(df$Variable 1, df[,i], method = "kendall") 
  b[i,] <- cbind(colnames(df)[i], a$estimate, a$p.value)
}
```

How could i go about to calculate the correlation on a daily basis ? Meaning i get a value of correlation for each day of my data set.
I would be thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Without a sample of your data, it's hard to reproduce your exact problem, but here's an example using `tidyverse` to do grouping and calculation with the mtcars data set.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
    select(cyl, disp, hp) %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise(disp_hp_cor_test = list(cor.test(disp, hp))) %>%
    mutate(disp_hp_cor = unlist(map(disp_hp_cor_test, "estimate")),
           disp_hp_pval = unlist(map(disp_hp_cor_test, "p.value")))

#     cyl disp_hp_cor_test disp_hp_cor disp_hp_pval
#   <dbl> <list>                 <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1     4 <htest>                0.435        0.182
# 2     6 <htest>               -0.514        0.238
# 3     8 <htest>                0.118        0.687
```

The main idea here is that you are trying to perform a grouped correlation test, which is possible using `group_by` and `summarise` from **`dplyr`**. Then we just need to do a little work within `mutate` to pull out our measures of interest (correlation and pvalue).

Another, potentially cleaner option, would be to use `across`. This would also make it easier to work with multiple `cor.test` within the same data.frame:

```
mtcars %>%
    select(cyl, disp, hp, wt) %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise(disp_hp_cor_test = list(cor.test(disp, hp)),
              disp_wt_cor_test = list(cor.test(disp, wt))) %>%
    mutate(across(c(disp_hp_cor_test, disp_wt_cor_test), 
                  list("estimate" = ~unlist(map(.x, "estimate")),
                       "p.value" = ~unlist(map(.x, "p.value")))))

    cyl disp_hp_cor_test disp_wt_cor_test disp_hp_cor_test_e~ disp_hp_cor_test_~ disp_wt_cor_test_~ disp_wt_cor_test~
  <dbl> <list>           <list>                         <dbl>              <dbl>              <dbl>             <dbl>
1     4 <htest>          <htest>                        0.435              0.182              0.857          0.000761
2     6 <htest>          <htest>                       -0.514              0.238              0.473          0.284   
3     8 <htest>          <htest>                        0.118              0.687              0.755          0.00179
```

Comment: bouncyball, I was working on something very similar. Your method of a list-column for the `cor.test` is what I had momentarily forgotten, but is there not a way with `mutate`/`summarize` to assign two values from a function? The `data.table` analog would be `DT[, c("est","pv") := cor.test(disp, hp)[c("estimate","p.value")], by =.(cyl)]`.

Comment: I would probably use `tidy` from the __`broom`__ package to extract multiple columns from `cor.test` at once.

Comment: and to actually answer your question, I don't think a _good_ way to do this exists: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5494

Comment: Actually ... *that works*. I didn't believe it until I tried. `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(as.data.frame(cor.test(disp,hp)[c("estimate","p.value")]))` works. I learned something new today, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are amenable to using `data.table`, here's the same thing as @bouncyball's excellent `dplyr` suggestion in `data.table`-speak:

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(mtcars)
DT[, c("est","pv") := cor.test(disp, hp)[c("estimate","p.value")], by =.(cyl)]

head(DT)
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb        est        pv
#    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>      <num>     <num>
# 1:  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4     4 -0.5136284 0.2383485
# 2:  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4 -0.5136284 0.2383485
# 3:  22.8     4   108    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1  0.4346051 0.1816262
# 4:  21.4     6   258   110  3.08 3.215 19.44     1     0     3     1 -0.5136284 0.2383485
# 5:  18.7     8   360   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2  0.1182556 0.6872155
# 6:  18.1     6   225   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     1     0     3     1 -0.5136284 0.2383485
```

You'll need to handle pairs of variables manually using this (and bouncyball's) technique.

```r
DT <- as.data.table(mtcars)
DT[, c("est1","pv1") := cor.test(disp, hp)[c("estimate","p.value")], by =.(cyl)]
DT[, c("est2","pv2") := cor.test(disp, mpg)[c("estimate","p.value")], by =.(cyl)]
DT[, c("est3","pv3") := cor.test(hp, mpg)[c("estimate","p.value")], by =.(cyl)]

head(DT)
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb       est1       pv1       est2         pv2       est3        pv3
#    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>      <num>     <num>      <num>       <num>      <num>      <num>
# 1:  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4     4 -0.5136284 0.2383485  0.1030827 0.825929685 -0.1270678 0.78602021
# 2:  21.0     6   160   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4 -0.5136284 0.2383485  0.1030827 0.825929685 -0.1270678 0.78602021
# 3:  22.8     4   108    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1  0.4346051 0.1816262 -0.8052361 0.002782827 -0.5235034 0.09839858
# 4:  21.4     6   258   110  3.08 3.215 19.44     1     0     3     1 -0.5136284 0.2383485  0.1030827 0.825929685 -0.1270678 0.78602021
# 5:  18.7     8   360   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2  0.1182556 0.6872155 -0.5197670 0.056774876 -0.2836357 0.32575378
# 6:  18.1     6   225   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     1     0     3     1 -0.5136284 0.2383485  0.1030827 0.825929685 -0.1270678 0.78602021
```